# how to get Hamburger icon in ios app

Tags: ios, hamburger-menu

I am new to ios development, I should create ios app with Hamburger menu, my question is: is there a unicode for this icon, or should I use it as a picture.

Answer (score 8):

Actually there is an Hamburger, check it out

**Edit** > **Special Characters** (control + cmd + space)

It is under the bell section:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `U+2261` unicode character.

Comment: should I add this as a string, I tried that already. did not work

Answer (score 0):

No, hamburger is actually not recommended by apple design employees, but that doesn't mean you can't put it in!

Either you put it in as a image asset or use a font like [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/).